# Automapper validate source and destination members

Tags: validation, automapper-9

I've been using Automapper but this is my first 9.0 automapper use. I'd like Automapper to complain whenever a new field pops up in the source *or* the destination and I have no two-way mappings.

By trying out I've found out that

```
CreateMap<IViewCreationData, View>()
               .ValidateMemberList(MemberList.Source | MemberList.Destination)
               .ForMember(dest => dest.aaa, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.a))
               .ForMember(dest => dest.bbb, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.b))
               .ForMember(dest => dest.ccc, opt => opt.Ignore())
               .ForMember(dest => dest.ddd, opt => opt.Ignore())
               .ForSourceMember(src => src.eee, opt => opt.DoNotValidate());
```

seems to do the trick. Only, I get a warning that the `MemberList` enum has no `[Flags]` Attribute. My question is now, is this *supposed* to work, i.e. can I rely on it, or is this just a coincidence that can go away in the next version?

Comment: No, you need two maps for that.

Comment: Did you post this as a feature suggestion on the GitHub project?  If so, please link to it - I would definitely upvote it, as I have some situations where I'd prefer two-way validation.